# Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379] change REDIS_HOST value still does'nt work

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

Need a help! My code was run on Docker and get problem with Redis.

I've checked on server the Redis is running.

I also try change in .env file **REDIS_HOST=redis** --> **REDIS_HOST=localhost** and **REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1** but does'nt work anymore!

REDIS_HOST=redis

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379]
```

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 or REDIS_HOST=localhost

```
Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

docker ps | grep redis

```
365ba9ede8e0        redis                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 hours ago         Up 7 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp           redis
3e94135b4c83        redis:alpine                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 5 hours          6379/tcp                         ms-worker_redis_1
69d8708931e6        redis:alpine                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          6379/tcp                         ma-worker-redis-service
810c182d403d        redis:alpine                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          6379/tcp                         ma-redis-service
```

Comment: What's the container's name? Are they sharing network?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your `docker-compose.yml` file, or the specific `docker run` commands you're using to start the Redis and application containers?

Comment: @abestrad
Yes, this is my company server. Have a lot of services and web app running on that./

Comment: @TienNguyen Your containers need a network to communicate. If you are not using docker-compose take a look at this https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/

Comment: Sorry these guys abestrad, snahor, David Maze.
That is my fault.
On my sever they setup port for everything at 192.168.0.1.
To fix is simple set REDIS_HOST=redis -> REDIS_HOST=192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. It turned out that it was necessary to add radish to the application network

```
redis:
    image: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass ${REDIS_KEY}
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    networks:
      - web
```

[image]